# Redux configureStore erros after adding another reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

my current store looks like this:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import notesReducer from "./notesReducer";
import todoReducer from "./todoReducer";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: todoReducer, // here i wanna add a notesReducer
});
export default store;
```

As said, i wanna add a notesReducer and what i have seen in tutorial i could do it by that:

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: { todo: todoReducer, note: notesReducer }, 
});
```

But this althoug, deploy an errror in my Todos.js file: `TypeError: props.todos.map is not a function`

Whole Todos.js file so you could help me finding the solution or things I did wrong:
https://pastebin.com/AWyg8BXW

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your `mapStateToProps` be

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    todos: state.todos,
  };
};
```

Comment: ×
Error: "reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers

Comment: @learningbtw right, i misread the docs. Updated with the likely problem.

Comment: Still: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'). Acorrding to the same {props.todos.map((item). I will try rewriting the component once again maybe

Comment: @learningbtw can you post your `todos` reducer as well ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4ffxHJxe

Comment: I probably found the solution. instead of const [todo, setTodo] = useState(""); i should pass an array... const [todo, setTodo] = useState([]);

Comment: @learningbtw seems to work fine for me, with the change to the `mapStateToProps`. See https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-lichterman-6scwp